# SOAP request with complex type in PHP

Tags: php, soap, complextype

I would like to make a SOAP request with complex types... I have two different variables:

```
<!--type: string-->               
        <xsd:type>PC</xsd:type><xsd:property>
<!--type: string-->
```

and:

```
<xsd:deviceId xsi:type="xsd1:LogicalDeviceId" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">           
         <xsd1:id>234</xsd1:id>
</xsd:deviceId>
```

Anyone has an idea how to create these two variables?

Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Are you using the native PHP SOAP or the nuSOAP library? Can you provide the full SOAP envelope so that we have some context to work from? What have you tried so far? We may have a better idea of where to go from when we have this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP SoapClient to create the complex types, for example:

```
$deviceId = new SoapVar(array("xsd1:id" => 1234), XSD_ANYTYPE, "xsd1:LogicalDeviceId", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "deviceId");


$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://yoursoaptarget");
$soapClient->yourSoapMethod($deviceId, <other params);
```

See more details on SoapVar in the PHP documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php